# VLAN tag insertion on outgoing packet

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, vlan

I am working to insert vlan tags for some client macs on outgoing packets via native vlan. I have tried nh_hooks IN, OUT and Forward but didn't get any success.

Can I either: add the tag to the packet from client coming to native VLAN and then send it via same VLAN, can I forward native VLAN packets of some clients based on their MAC to a tagged VLAN interface?

Any suggestion in netlink nh hooks code or kernel level code? Is it possible to do that via ebtables based on MAC?

Comment: Do you need to to do it on MacOS or linux side?

Comment: On linux side. Tried netfilter hooks to manipulate skbuff but couldnt suceeded.